# server version: 9.3.2; pg_dump version: 9.1.9 rails with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am using rails with postgres database, I am trying to do a rake db:migrate and I obtain this error.

```
server version: 9.3.2; pg_dump version: 9.1.9
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
rake aborted!
```

I have both version of postgres 9.3.2 and 9.1.9 but how activate the last one!!!

```
postgres           67   0,0  0,1  2476740   7768   ??  Ss    9:07AM   0:00.18 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data
postgres           66   0,0  0,2  2592204  13700   ??  Ss    9:07AM   0:00.19 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to install Postgres 9.3 with homebrew, and the edit your .bash_profile to direct your $PATH to Postgres 9.3, (and subsequently pg_dump 9.3)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Not the greatest solution, but if you're using a Mac a version of Postgres is already installed and homebrew installs another in a different location.

If you don't want to go through all of that, I'd check out this documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgupgrade.html